# WiFi Certificates Accidentally Deleted

Tags: macos, network, wifi, security, keychain

I accidentally deleted some certificates from the Keychain Access application and I think they were somehow related to WiFi networks.  Now everytime I try to join a network that uses PEAP authentication, it tells me to Accept the certificate (no password to unlock).

I looked at [Why does OS X repeatedly prompt for certificate trust when joining WPA2 Enterprise WiFi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234952/why-does-os-x-repeatedly-prompt-for-certificate-trust-when-joining-wpa2-enterpri) and added all the certificates as trusted, but that doesn't help.

Also, I suspect that this has caused my WiFi to become less reliable, i.e. my connection drops more frequently, and things like that.

How do I solve this? Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Try this: https://www.macissues.com/2015/09/10/fix-persistent-invalid-certificate-errors/

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? Did you talk with your network admin (if you are not the person) about re-certifiing the PEAP Cert?

Comment: No, the problem is still unsolved.  @kenjikato could you perhaps point me towards something that discusses PEAP Certificates in general?

Comment: gunner I think there are loads of articles online, here is a [nice overview](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SCJKrg0ZdzkJ:searchnetworking.techtarget.com/answer/Can-you-help-me-understand-the-differences-between-WPA2-and-Ciscos-LEAP-security-Is-one-better-or+) to start with.  Using google cache because the original is not https.